# How to Bind two textboxes into 1 variable in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angular app, In this app i have a form. I have a button click action for form submittion called onActivitySubmit().

In the form i want to get something called "Distance" for that i have to textboxes. two boxes are for the distance number and another one to fill KM or Meters.

So after submiting the form i want to pass this as an one value to the database. How do i do that? For an example i if i have 2 in one textbox and KM in another box i want to pass this as an one value to the database(mongo) as 2KM.

this is my button click event.

```
onActivitySubmit() {

this.processing = true;
const activity = {
  distance: this.form.get('distance').value,
  type: this.form.get('type').value,
  postedBy: this.username,
}
this.activityService.newActivity(activity).subscribe(data => {
  if(!data.success) {

  } else {

  }
})
```

}

Comment: do you know anything about `concatenation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
const activity = {
  distance: this.form.get('distance').value.toString() + this.form.get('type').value ,
  type: this.form.get('type').value,
  postedBy: this.username,
}
```

Comment: Then he want  remove the space. it's just a common sense.  :) any way I have update my answer

Comment: But what I don't understand is why you are putting ''?Won't this work distance: this.form.get('distance').value.toString() +this.form.get('type').value ?

Comment: Because if the distance value is integer. it may be threw conversion error. that's why I have convert to string then concatenate. previously am not using toString(). that's why am using ''. but any way we won't it. i'll update it. thanks for your attention

Comment: The please give me the mark as answer @RoshiniDissanayake

Comment: How do i do that? Where ?

Comment: Click the green tick button... In center of the up and down vote Button @ros

Comment: Done ! :) Also can you tell me how to get type from a option box? for that click event?

Comment: <div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
    <option>KM</option>
    <option>M</option>

  </select>
</div>

Comment: from this select box ?

Comment: Ask this as a new question